# If I download viruses on a virtual machine, can they infect the host?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 computer and am running Windows 10 in the virtual machine (Virtual box). If i wanted to download lots of viruses to screw with the virtual machine, could they infect the host? I know about turning shared folders off. If they can infect the host, *is there any way to make it so they can't, but i still want to be able to browse the internet in the vm.* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No,  Virii can't interfere with the host in a VirtualBox VM because it emulates everything, so from the Viruses point of view the VM is its world.

Of-course, there are exceptions - if the Virus has the ability to propogate itself, it could attempt to propogate itself and have better access to your LAN then it otherwise would (ie it might be on the trusted side of a firewall), and if you did later on do other things with the image (like copying files out of it) it could spread that way.

Comment: While everything you said is true, being able to detect if the machine is a VM is possible, which means in theory a virus if it exploited a vulnerability in a hypervisor could infect a host.

Comment: Ramhound - are you aware of any such vulnerabilities for virtual box?

Comment: There has been vulnerabilities in the past

Comment: davidgo - Is there any way to make sure that what you have described in your answer does not happen, while still being able to have access to the internet in the guest?